# Outlook reply with individual recipient names (sender name of original email)

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have created a macro in Outlook VBA below that replies with the sender first name added to the greeting, adds some text for the body, and adds a signature in the fonts I want.

What I need help with is getting the macro to pull ALL of the names of the senders, assigning a value to them that I can then place elsewhere in the body of the email.  If that cannot be done, I would settle for just getting all of the names into the greeting, though it is much preferred to be able to move the names around.

Example:  sender was Name1;Name2
Currently, this macro will pull only Name1 (giving "Dear Name1,"), but
I would like to get to "Dear Name1 and Name2," at the very least.
Best would be able to have Name1 be in the greeting, then Name2 is placed in the body of the text.

I believe I have taken this as far as I can on my own and now turn to you experts for assistance!  Thank you!!

```
Sub AutoAddGreetingtoReply()
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim oReply As MailItem
Dim GreetTime As String
Dim strbody As String
Dim SigString As String
Dim Signature As String
Dim R As Outlook.Recipient
Dim strGreetName As String

Select Case Application.ActiveWindow.Class
       Case olInspector
            Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
       Case olExplorer
            Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
End Select




strbody = "<H3><B></B></H3>" & _
"<br><br><B></B>" & _
          "Please visit this website to view your transactions.<br>" & _
          "Let me know if you have problems.<br>" & _
          "<A HREF=""http://www.google.com"">Questions</A>" & _
          "<br><br>Thank you"

          SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
            "\Microsoft\Signatures\90 Days.htm"

On Error Resume Next

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
          strGreetName = Left$(oMail.SenderName, InStr(1, oMail.SenderName, " ") - 1)
End If

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
Else
    Signature = ""
End If

Set oReply = oMail.ReplyAll

With oReply
    .CC = ""
    .HTMLBody = "<Font Face=calibri>Dear " & strGreetName & "," & R1 & strbody & "<br>" & Signature
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: On Error Resume Next hinders learning. http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Answer (score 1):

Given a string "First Last" then get the right side of the string like this

```
sndrName = oMail.SenderName
lastName = right(sndrName, len(sndrName) - InStr(1, sndrName, " "))
```

Using the format in your code:

```
strGreetName = Left$(oMail.SenderName, InStr(1, oMail.SenderName, " ") - 1)
lastName = right(oMail.SenderName, len(oMail.SenderName) - InStr(1, oMail.SenderName, " "))
```

If there is a space in the text InStr returns the position. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function

Original mail has one sender. A ReplyAll has recipients, including the original mail sender.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ReplyFirstNames()

Dim oMail As mailitem
Dim oReply As mailitem

Dim strGreetName As String
Dim strGreetNameAll As String

Dim i As Long

Select Case Application.ActiveWindow.Class
    Case olInspector
        Set oMail = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    Case olExplorer
        Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
End Select

Set oReply = oMail.ReplyAll

With oReply

    Debug.Print "The reply all recipients are:"

    For i = 1 To .Recipients.count
        Debug.Print .Recipients(i)

        ' Given the format First Last
        strGreetName = Left(.Recipients(i), InStr(1, .Recipients(i), " ") - 1)
        strGreetNameAll = strGreetNameAll & strGreetName & ", "
    Next i

    Debug.Print strGreetNameAll
    ' remove extra comma and space from end
    strGreetNameAll = Left(strGreetNameAll, Len(strGreetNameAll) - 2)
    Debug.Print strGreetNameAll

    .htmlbody = "<Font Face=calibri>" & strGreetNameAll & .htmlbody
    .Display

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, but please forgive me.  I am not sure how to do what you said.  I tried to add that code and dimmed the items as  strings, but got object variable error.  I am just learning all this, so I appreciate any help and guidance you can give me, thank you!  What does InStr do?  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks again Niton, I got that to work (an accomplishment in itself, trust me!).   So that pulls the last name of the person, but what I am looking to also do is get the name of the second person that was in the sender line.  So when I hit reply, it will pull both names and insert in the greeting.  So it is dear Sender1 and Sender2.  Do you know how I could identify the second sender and then apply your code?  I was thinking it would be something like oMail.SenderName2 or something like that, but I do not know how Outlook handles the designations.  Thank you so much once again!

Comment: Wow, awesome, that was able to get all the names, how did you do that?  Is it the .recipients piece or the strgreetnameall piece maybe?  I tried to run a stub macro to get these two pieces to work together, but no go so far.  Is there a way I can get these two to work together, so it takes those names and adds them to my code so it adds them to the greeting before the body?  You are a genius!

Comment: This should be helpful in figuring out how it works. http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx  If not, try asking a new question.

Comment: Hi Niton, thank you again, you have been so helpful and I have been learning a lot.  I read that and was able to get it to work!  I have learned that the .recipients object pulls all names, but what if I want to just pull the names in the To or the CC, separately?  I have some code I tried out, setting the strings as strTO and strCC, but cannot get them to work with the overall code.  Can you provide any guidance on this piece?  So if I ran this, it might reply with ONLY the To names in the greeting.  I have been successful via your teaching in extracting specific names,but cannot exclude CC.

Comment: Here is the new code I have to get just the To or the CC but cannot get it to incorporate right:                                                                                              Dim strTo As String, strCC As String

Set Recipients = oResponse.Recipients
For i = 1 To Recipients.Count
Set R = Recipients.Item(i)

Debug.Print R.Name, R.Type

If R.Type = olCC Then
strCC = R.Name & ", " & strCC
Else
strTo = R.Name & ", " & strTo
End If
Next

Comment: Try asking a new question with enough code to demonstrate the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay cool, will do that, thanks so much.  I will link to it once I have it up!  I am so close to getting this, and I think it would help many others out there.

Comment: I asked the question, it is here now:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207443/outlook-reply-with-sender-names-in-greeting-and-body